# Is there a way to force ignore duplicate symbols on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

While trying to build PyMesh from source, I encounter the following error in make

```
[ 49%] Linking CXX shared library ../../../python/pymesh/lib/libPyMesh-IGL.dylib
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for CORE::Realbase_for<long>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo for CORE::Realbase_for<long>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for CORE::Realbase_for<double>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo for CORE::Realbase_for<double>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for CORE::Realbase_for<CORE::BigInt>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo for CORE::Realbase_for<CORE::BigInt>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'typeinfo name for CORE::ConstPolyRep<CORE::BigInt>' in:
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/CellPartition.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/MinkowskiSum.cpp.o
ld: 22 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../python/pymesh/lib/libPyMesh-IGL.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [tools/IGL/CMakeFiles/lib_IGL.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However, this error does not occur on Linux.
Is there any way to ignore the duplicate symbols on the MacOS Linker?

Comment: Why would you want to *ignore* duplicate symbols? They are a bug in your code. Fix the problem, don't ignore it.

Comment: The thing is that this is third party code. I'm trying to build a python library called PyMesh from source. Also, this error doesn't show up on Linux which is why I was asking